# Should hadoop installation path be the same across nodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Hadoop 2.7 is installed at `/opt/pro/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3` at master, then the whole installation is copied to slave, but different directory `/opt/pro/hadoop-2.7.3`.  I then update the environment variables (e.g., HADOOP_HOME, hdfs_site.xml for namenode and datanode) at slave machine.

Now I can run `hadoop version` at slave successfully. However, in the master, `start-dfs.sh` fails with message:

```
17/02/18 10:24:32 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [master]
master: starting namenode, logging to /opt/pro/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-shijiex-namenode-shijie-ThinkPad-T410.out
master: starting datanode, logging to /opt/pro/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-shijiex-datanode-shijie-ThinkPad-T410.out
slave: bash: line 0: cd: /opt/pro/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3: No such file or directory
slave: bash: /opt/pro/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /opt/pro/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-shijiex-secondarynamenode-shijie-ThinkPad-T410.out
17/02/18 10:26:15 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

The hadoop uses the `HADOOP_HOME` of master(`/opt/pro/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3`) at slave, while the `HADOOP_HOME` at slave is `/opt/pro/hadoop-2.7.3`. 
So should the **HADOOP_HOME** be the same across nodes when installation?

---

.bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin

export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/pro/hadoop-2.7.3
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
# Add Hadoop bin/ directory to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

hadoop-env.sh

```
# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

At slave server, $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop has a file masters:

```
xx@wodaxia:/opt/pro/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop$ cat masters 
master
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Not necessarily. But if the paths are different among the nodes, then you cannot use the scripts like `start-dfs.sh`, `stop-dfs.sh` and the same for `yarn`. These scripts refer the `$HADOOP_PREFIX` variable of the node where the script is executed.

Snippet of code from `hadoop-daemons.sh` used by `start-dfs.sh` to start all the datanodes.

```
exec "$bin/slaves.sh" --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR cd "$HADOOP_PREFIX" \; "$bin/hadoop-daemon.sh" --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR "$@"
```

The script is written this way because of the assumption that all the nodes of cluster follow the same `$HADOOP_PREFIX` or `$HADOOP_HOME` (deprecated) path.

To overcome this,

1) Either try to have the path same across all the nodes.

2) Or login to each node in the cluster and start the dfs process applicable for that node using,

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start <namenode | datanode | secondarynamenode| journalnode>
```

Same procedure for yarn as well,

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start <resourcemanager | nodemanager>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not. $HADOOP_HOME is individual per each Hadoop node, but it can be instantiated by different ways. You can define it in global way by setting it in **.bashrc** file or it can be set in local **hadoop-env.sh** script in your Hadoop folder for example. Verify that the values are the same on every node of the cluster. If it is global you can check it by **echo $HADOOP_HOME**. If it is a script option, you can verify this variable by importing it into current context and checking it again:

```
. /opt/pro/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/bin/hadoop-env.sh
echo $HADOOP_HOME
```

Besides make sure that you don't have **hadoop.home.dir** property in your configuration, as it overrides environmental $HADOOP_HOME

Comment: I confirm the environment variables in ``.bashrc`` is correct, and I did not add any new variable in etc/hadoop/*xml. Not sure whether it is related to masters at the slave server. Anyway, I force the installation to be consistent at both server as a work around currently.